# snowflake uses the cloud providers to store the data then why do we have database concepts in snowflake?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake is a cloud-based data warehousing platform that leverages cloud providers' infrastructure to store and manage data. It utilizes the storage capabilities of the cloud provider to store data, specifically object storage such as Amazon S3 for AWS or Azure Blob Storage for Microsoft Azure. Then why snowflake has brought the concept of data base objects like tables, schemas etc..? My understanding the data retriveal or to access the strored data only SQL or database design concept only the way to do it ?

Comment: Snowflake is a relational DBMS (with a lot of additional functionality) - so your

Comment: No bro, Snowflake is not a traditional relational database management system (DBMS) in the typical sense. Instead, Snowflake is a cloud-based data warehousing platform.

Snowflake provides the functionality of a fully managed data warehouse, allowing users to store, process, and analyze large volumes of data in a scalable and efficient manner. It has a SQL-based query engine, which means you can interact with it using SQL commands just like you would with a relational database. However, its underlying architecture and design go beyond that of a standard relational database.

Comment: I think we are just arguing about definitions. I don’t know what you mean by a “traditional” RDBMS in the “typical” sense. Snowflake stores data in tables and columns that you can query using SQL - that makes it an RDBMS. The fact that it has additional functionality doesn’t mean it stops being an RDBMS at its core. Also, Snowflake’s capabilities go far beyond data warehousing - so it is not just a data warehousing platform, that’s just part of its capabilities

Comment: I dont agree that snowflake makes it an RDBMS , snowfalke is not an database application they have just created a database layer on top of cloud based object storage. in way they provide SQL based querying to query or access data from cloud...

Comment: Ok - we’re obviously both entitled to our own views and continuing this discussion seems pointless

Comment: Snowflake also has Snowpark, which can access Snowflake data as dataframes.  So, not just SQL and not just tables.  But I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake is a relational DBMS (with a lot of additional functionality) - so you are basically asking why a database has tables and schemas.

If you want to understand the Snowflake architecture and what makes it different from many other DBMSs then I would start by reading the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts